# Nested foreach won't work

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I cannot get a nested foreach to work. I have the following code:

HTML - Snippet

```
<div data-bind='foreach: choice'>
    <p data-bind='foreach: id'>
        <input name="group1" type="radio" data-bind="attr: { id: $data }"/> <label  data-bind="attr: { for: $data} "> <span data-bind=" text: $data"> </span>
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Javascript - Snippet

```
var questionModel = { 
question : ko.observable(), 
id: ko.observableArray(), 
choice: ko.observableArray() 
}

function startTest() {
    questionModel.question(questions[questionNo].question);
    var m = [];
    var i = [];

    var e = 0;
    while (e != 4) {
        m.push(choices[questionNo][e].choice);
        i.push(choices[questionNo][e].id);
        e++;
    }

    questionModel.choice(m);
    questionModel.id(i);
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is for each choice to be generated within a radio button and to have the IDs within the array be the id for the radio button and label. I've successfully displayed the choices on it's own. But when I added the **data-bind='foreach: id'** & **data-bind='attr: { id: $data }'**, that's when things stopped working. I keep getting the error below:

> ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return
>   id }" Message: id is not defined

**Disclaimer: I've tested the data and everything for the arrays are fine.**

Comment: I think the problem is that you are creating two arrays that are not truly nested. The `id` is a property of the `choice` object. Try removing the paragraph tag `<p data-bind='foreach: id'>` and see if it works.

Comment: @styfle the radio button id is the same as the choice with your above solution, that isn't what I'm looking for. The id is not a property of the choice object. What I'm looking for is this. I have the choice array ('Water', 'Air','Land, 'Sea') and the id array ('1','2','3','4'). The radio button should be 'water' with the id being '1', the next radio button should be 'air' with the id being '2' & so on.

Comment: Do you want 4 inputs: `water:1, air:2, land:3, sea:4`? Or do you want 16 inputs: `water:1, air:1, land:1, sea:1, water:2, air:2, land:2, sea:2...`?

Comment: @styfle The first.

Comment: Can you add the raw JSON data?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for not using your code layout, I couldn't find where questions was declared or where the bindings were applied. I made an example here using a simple 3 item data model, `QuestionModel`, and a simple view model containing it.

The data model just contains the ID for the question, the question itself (`title`) and then the choices for that question. Loop through each question, and then each of the choices. You can expand on the choices for values or whatever if you'd like. Just make an array of objects.

```
[{ 
  "AnswerText": "Blue", 
  "AnswerValue" : "#0000FF"
}]
```

```js
function QuestionModel(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.Id = ko.observable(data.Id);
  self.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);
  self.Choices = ko.observableArray(data.Choices);

}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.Questions = ko.observableArray([
    new QuestionModel({
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "What color are rabbits?",
      "Choices": ["Red", "Blue", "Green"]
    }),
    new QuestionModel({
      "Id": 2,
      "Title": "What color are dogs?",
      "Choices": ["Silver ", "Golden", "Striped"]
    }),
    new QuestionModel({
      "Id": 3,
      "Title": "What color are cats?",
      "Choices": ["white", "Black", "Orange"]
    })
  ]);

}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: Questions">
  <span data-bind="text: Title"> </span>
  <div data-bind="foreach: Choices">
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data, attr : {name : $parent.Id}" />
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is not part of `choice`, you need to use `$parent` to reference it:

```
data-bind="foreach: $parent.id"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbest/08gk7h4v/

Answer (score 0):

You should add an array of choices that look like `{id: 1}` to the model. Then you can loop over the choices and reference the `id` property like so:

```js
var questionModel = {
  question: ko.observable(),
  choice: ko.observableArray()
}

function startTest() {
  questionModel.question(questions[questionNo].question);
  var m = [];
  var e = 0;
  while (e != 4) {
    var choice = choices[questionNo][e];
    m.push(choice);
    e++;
  }

  questionModel.choice(m);
}
```

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: choice">
  <p>
    <input name="group1" type="radio" data-bind="attr: { id: id }" />
    <label data-bind="attr: { for: id }">
        <span data-bind="text: id"> </span>
        </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: See the docs here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting everything I'm explaining or misunderstanding the code. There is already an array of IDs in the code. I just need them to be added as IDs for the radio buttons. Your above solution didn't provide any means for the choice itself to be displayed as a label for the radio button. Noticed I had an id array in the questionModel.